# how to write onclick event for href tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Can anybody help me out writing this on onClick event on href tag?

```
 string x= "<a href=\"JavaScript:callfunction(event,'"+ y.id.tostring() + "');\">click</a>";
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is it doing? What is your question?

Answer (score 6):

```
string x = string.Format(
    "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"callfunction(event, '{0}')\">click</a>", 
    y.id
);
```

Answer (score 4):

why not something like :

```
string x= "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"callfunction(event,'"+ y.id.tostring() + "');\">click</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternative way using DOM responsible methods for this kind of task

```
var x     = document.createElement('a');
x.href    = "#";
x.onclick = function(evt) {
   callfunction(evt, y.id.tostring())
}

<destination-node>.appendChild(x);
```